# How do I use OGG with SDL_Mixer?

Tags: xcode, sdl-2, sdl-mixer, oggvorbis

I can't seem to get SDL_Mixer to initialize with OGG support enabled. I know that I must link with libogg, libvorbis and libvorbisfile but it still won't work. I have `.dylib`s, `.framework`s and `.a`s of these three libraries and I've tried them all.

I'm copying the dylibs/frameworks into the Frameworks folder of the app package in the build phases tab.

I have `Runpath Search Paths` set to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` in the build settings tab.

But `Mix_Init(MIX_INIT_OGG)` keeps returning the error `OGG support not available`.

I'm using the latest Homebrew versions of all of the mentioned libraries. I'm not sure what else to try.

I have a finished game with 300MB of `wav`s as the music.

### Update

I’ve managed to mix some Objective C with C++ and get some sound playing with `AVAudioPlayer` but it’s horrendous code. I’m having to cast to `void *` to make sure my music player class is compatible with my C++ code base. The garbage collector is so annoying. All it does is get in your way. You have to fight it with bridge casts.

I’d really like to use SDL_Mixer or a simple C library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Objective C music player fully implemented but I just can’t stand Objective C. I found a brilliant library called [stb_vorbis](https://nothings.org/stb_vorbis/). I’ve used a few of the other [stb libraries](https://github.com/nothings/stb) so I knew this one would be great. Playing the audio data from this library is actually pretty easy. All I really had to do was call `stb_vorbis_get_samples_short_interleaved` inside of SDL2’s audio callback. I didn’t have to do any mixing because I only need to play music. The implementation was so simple that it actually worked perfectly the first time I ran it! This because stb_vorbis and SDL2 are both C libraries so they just make sense (unlike Objective C which should be burned).

**TL;DR**

If you just want to play music and either can’t use SDL_Mixer or don’t want to use SDL_Mixer then you can just feed the data from [stb_vorbis](https://nothings.org/stb_vorbis/) into [SDL2’s audio callback](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_OpenAudioDevice).